# Spring Security add Authorities

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

We have migrated from Spring security 3.0.5 to 3.2.5. We were using below code for adding authorities.

```
 UserDetails loadedUser = new UserDetails();
 loadedUser.getAuthorities().add(new GrantedAuthorityImpl("ROLE_ADMIN"));
```

Now this code is giving below error

The method add(capture#1-of ? extends GrantedAuthority) in the type Collection is not applicable for the arguments (GrantedAuthorityImpl)

Can some one please help me with this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a reason why the interface [GrantedAuthority](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/GrantedAuthority.html) provides only a getter but not setter, those objects are meant to be immutable. Enforce a logout/login on permission change and set the authorities on object creation like [this](http://www.javaroots.com/2013/03/how-to-use-custom-dao-classe-in-spring.html).

Answer (score -1):

Probably you have to use [**SimpleGrantedAuthority**](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.5.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/authority/SimpleGrantedAuthority.html),

GrantedAuthorityImpl is deprecated now

Comment: Hi @kuhajevan i tried this but it is giving same error.